# elsif a letter contained in an array

Tags: ruby, include, each

How would I basically say within the elsif below "if letter == (a letter contained within the array "letterbank") ===> print letter"

```
def hide_or_not(an_array, a_guess)
    an_array.each do |letter|
      if a_guess == letter
        print a_guess
      elsif SOMETHING HERE
        print letter
      else
        print "_"
      end
    end
  end
```

assuming the method is fed a_guess which is a letter in string form and an array of single letters.  When a letter is guessed, it appears, or else a "_" is printed

```
an_array = ["r", "i", "c", "s", "h", "a", "w"]
letter_guess = "r"
```

then sorry I also assuming I have to save each letter guessed so I want to somewhere inlcude a letterbank. I don't know if I should do that below the moethod or within it... (already guessed letters)

```
letterbank = ["s", "w", "t", "j"]
```

so in this case, I would want the below to print... thanks!

```
r___s__w
```

Comment: `letterbank.include? letter`

Comment: Hint: Strings are effectively character arrays. Making literal arrays of characters is wasteful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is using a string instead of array but can just as easily use arrays. (Adding the chars to a string and printing after completing the iteration gives some extra flexibility in the printing for example allowing you to use `puts`).

```
class LetterGuesser # Hangman
  def initialize(word) 
    @word = word;
    @guessed_letters = '';
  end

  def guess_letter(letter)
    @guessed_letters << letter if !@guessed_letters.include?(letter)
    current_guesses = ''
    @word.each_char do |char| 
      if guessed_letters.include?(char) 
        current_guesses << letter 
      else
        current_guesses << '_' 
      end
    end
    puts current_guesses
  end
end

game = LetterGuesser.new('test')
game.guess_letter('e')
```

Comment: Using a class is a good way of encapsulating this. One thing to note here is a lot of this code can be compacted down considerably with more effective use of Enumerable and other Ruby features like `if` supplying a return value to reduce duplication.

Comment: @tadman :thumsbup: Can definitely shorten it, but at the same time wanted to keep the answer in the style of the question so they can easily understand it and adjust it if necessary (e.g. adding the `elsif` which I wasn't sure its purpose).

Answer (score 1):

The most minimal solution here is to employ bare strings and [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-tr) to do the substitution for you:

```
def hide_or_not(word, guesses)
  word.tr('^' + guesses, '_')
end
```

Where you can see this working like this:

```
hide_or_not('rickshaw', 'r')
# => "r_______"

hide_or_not('rickshaw', 'rswtj')
=> "r___s__w"
```

Arrays and strings often work in largely the same ways, as in:

```
# Define an empty string
guesses = ''

# Append a character to the string
guesses << 'r'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a Hash instead of an Array.
Copy the letterbank values into a Hash mapping Letter to 1 (or true) to indicate the letter exists.

```
def hide_or_not(an_array, a_guess)
  letterbank = ["r", "s", "w", "t", "j"]
  letterhash = {} # define a new hash
  letterbank.each { |c| letterhash[c] = 1 } # copy array values into the hash

  an_array.each do |letter|
    if (a_guess == letter)
      print a_guess
    elsif letterhash[letter] # check if the letter is in the hash
      print letter
    else
      print "_"
    end
 end
```

end

```
an_array = ["r", "i", "c", "s", "h", "a", "w"]
hide_or_not(an_array, 'r')
```